# Update actor properties in game context

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am currently working on a plugin for the unreal engine 4.

Currently I am facing a problem when I want to modify my custom actor's properties in game context. When I am in the editor context, I can simply call the `PostEditChange` method. This method however does not exist in game context. 
How would you tackle this problem? Do I have to destroy the actor object and re-spawn it? Or is there a better method?

Example:

I wrote some setter-methods for my actor's properties in the following way:

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
void setProperty(<type> newValue){
    oldValue = newValue;
    this->PostEditChange(); //Only available in editor context
}
```

In the details panel I can see that the property value changes. However this doesn't have any visible effect.

Comment: Some code code example showing the actual issue you are facing would increase the probability of getting an answer

Comment: What is changing the property in the game context?

Comment: I want to change the properties via a blueprint script. For example bind a key to a specific property and increase/decrease it ingame.

Comment: > However this doesn't have any visible effect. <
What visible effect you expected? What property you changed?